# Metaget function NodeJS

Tags: node.js, function

I want to make a function that returns a meta tag by URL, using metaget.
So, by calling for example getMeta("http://google.com"); returns the title.

I've tried many things but can't get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `metaget` grabs `<meta>` tags from the markup. In this case, it sounds like you are interested in the `<title>` tag. Here's how I got it to work based on the `metaget` source code:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

function fetch (uri, callback) {
  var options = {
    url: uri,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'request'
    }
  };

  request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      var title = $('title');
      callback(null, title.text());
    }else{
      callback(new Error('Bad Request' + response.statusCode));
    }
  });
}

fetch('https://google.com', function (err, meta_response) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(meta_response);  // Outputs: Google
});
```

This just makes a request for the page data and uses `cheerio` to parse out the title tag text.